# Is there a way to load doubleclick.net ad tags on document.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-dfp, double-click-advertising

I tried to load `doubleclick.net` ad tags on `document.ready`, but the ads don't show up.

**HTML**

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" data-ad-src="http://ad.ch.doubleclick.net/adj/swisswebcams/;lng=de;kw=home;tile=3;dcopt=ist;sz=160x600;ord=1874680027?"></script>
```

**JavaScript (requires jQuery)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('script[data-ad-src]').each(function(){
    this.src = $(this).attr('data-ad-src');
    $(this).removeAttr('data-ad-src');
  });
});
```

---

The script shows up correct in the generated source code, but it doesn't load the ads anymore. Does the script require the document.ready event? Is there maybe a way to load this script just before document.ready - or to trigger document.ready again?

PS: I prefer to use the "sync" tags over the "async" tags, because "async" is creating an iFrame which then is not flexible in width/height anymore when showing 3rd party networks dynamically.

Comment: It might be, that further scripts are using `document.write` which seems not to work after `document.ready` - any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>
var wr = document.write, dchtml=[];
document.write=function(str) {
 // you may want to catch '<script' and add the src to the head when needed
 dchtml.push(str);
}
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" data-ad-src="http://ad.ch.doubleclick.net/adj/swisswebcams/;lng=de;kw=home;tile=3;dcopt=ist;sz=160x600;ord=1874680027?"></script>
<script>
$(function() { // assuming jQuery is loaded before this block
  $("#whereIWantMyAds").html(dchtml.join("\n"));
});
<script>
```

Comment: interesting code... what would you do with two ads on the same page?

Comment: Just do `<script>var dchtml=[];</script><script src...></script><script>$("#ad1").html(dchtml.join("\n")); dchtml=[];</script><script src...></script><script>$("#ad2").html(dchtml.join("\n"));</script>`

Comment: OK, this is exactly what I had in mind, but the problem is, that the document.write actually writes another script which then also includes a document.write, etc - also I have multiple ads on the page - and probably also other external scripts using document.write (sometimes).

Comment: @mplungjan So the biggest question is, how can I find out where the origin of the document.write is (in every case) without gessing. Is there something like a caller origin? See also my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844304/is-there-a-way-to-allow-document-write-after-document-ready?noredirect=1#comment44093162_27844304

Comment: indeed working fine with two ads, both using a document.write, but if you have a random number of ads, and you don't know all of them will have a document.write at all, you have to figure out another way besides the element's index to be able to place the code in the right spot...

Comment: A solution is to put each ad in its own iFrame and let it do what it wants

Answer (score 1):

Check your JavaScript errors. Most likely this is a problem with asynchronous downloading of the script, in fact: I'm sure. This is in the script from doubleclick (downloaded from the link you provided:

```
document.write('\x3cdiv...
```

a document.write doesn't work since document.ready already closed the document DOM. You specifically need to add the code to an element in your DOM, which can't be done with document.write. In order to make this work you have to either contact doubleclick and make them change every document.write to something that attaches the code to an element in your page, or asynchronously load the code (including the script) in an iframe.

Comment: Or rewrite document.write as I suggested

Comment: @mplungjan... and pray doubleclick doesn't put an extra script in their source...

Comment: Sure - but it is possible to catch that too.

Comment: Thank you, I think you nailed the problem. I found a possible workaround by "enabling" document.write after docment ready (as suggested by `mplungjan`) , but the new problem there seems to be to find out where to append the html. See my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844304/is-there-a-way-to-allow-document-write-after-document-ready?noredirect=1#comment44092674_27844304