# Is there a way to allow document.write after document.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to redefine the `document.ready`  function to capture what should have been written after document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 document.write = function(html){
    //... do something with HTML
 };
});
```

I do have the HTML now which should be rendered, but I don't know where it should belong to.

Is there a way to find out which script called the `document.write` function (in order to place the HTML code in the right place)?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but are you trying to override the `document.write` method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript - controlling the insertion point for document.write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536970/javascript-controlling-the-insertion-point-for-document-write)

Comment: redefine it outside of the ready event, and before any other scripts that might use it are loaded

Comment: `in order to place HTML code in the right place` - if you're trying to find out which script is doing such a thing than I'm 99% certain that they don't use document.write (because document.write will delete the page and insert the HTML into a blank page instead of placing it "in the right place"). Google about the DOM and innerHTML

Comment: @slebetman it is possible though if you consider a widget script that requires it to be placed in location within html that output is expected, but then you try to use alternate approach to asynchronously load that script such as ajax loading a template that includes the widget

Comment: @MelanciaUK Yes, because after the document is ready, document.write does not work anymore by default

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `document.write` in this situation. You use a jquery selector and the `.html()` method (or `.append()` or similar) to place content inside an element.

For example, if you had a `div` with the class `container`

```
var content = '<p>Some content</p>';
$('div.container').html(content);
```

this code would replace the contents of the container with the value of `content`. You'll notice that CSS style selectors are used for selecting elements, so to select the entire body you can use

```
$('body')
```

or for all text inputs, you can use

```
$('input[type="text"]')
```

`.html()` will replace the entire innner content, and `.append()` will add to the element after the other content.